# Why didn't Cedric explicitly tell Harry how to figure out the golden egg?

Tags: harry-potter

When Harry tells Cedric about the first task:

> "Dragons," said Harry ... "They've got four, one for each of us, and we've got to get past them."

It is very obvious that the task is battling a dragon.

However, when Cedric tells Harry to put the egg underwater:

> "Take a bath, and -- er -- take the egg with you, and -- er -- just mull things over in the hot water. It'll help you think.... Trust me."

He doesn't directly tell Harry how to listen to the egg's message.

Edit: Cedric also could have told Harry what the egg told him, e.g. "The second task is to rescue someone from the lake."

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cedric seems to be more observant of the actual rules than Harry, probably because he's a '*proper*' champion rather than an accidental entrant. It's made very clear that the contestants aren't supposed to be getting any support from their respective headmasters and presumably this also goes for champions helping each other out. He goes as far as he can without actually giving him the answer.

> ‘It’s all right,’ said Moody, sitting down and stretching out his
> wooden leg with a groan. ‘Cheating’s a traditional part of the
> Triwizard Tournament and always has been.’
>
> ‘I didn’t cheat,’ said Harry sharply. ‘It was – a sort of accident
> that I found out.’
>
> Moody grinned. ‘I wasn’t accusing you, laddie. I’ve been telling
> Dumbledore from the start, he can be as high minded as he likes, but
> you can bet old Karkaroff and Maxime won’t be. They’ll have told their
> champions everything they can. They want to win. They want to beat
> Dumbledore. They’d like to prove he’s only human.’

There's also the fact that Harry, given the antipathy between Cedric's supporters and himself, might simply ignore or disbelieve the advice given.

> Harry had not forgotten the hint that Cedric had given him, but **his
> less-than-friendly feelings towards Cedric just now meant that he was
> keen not to accept his help if he could avoid it. In any case, it
> seemed to him that if Cedric had really wanted to give Harry a hand,
> he would have been a lot more explicit.** He, Harry, had told Cedric
> exactly what was coming in the first task – and Cedric’s idea of a
> fair exchange had been to tell Harry to take a bath. Well, he didn’t
> need that sort of rubbishy help – not from someone who kept walking
> down corridors hand in hand with Cho, anyway. And so the first day of
> the new term arrived, and Harry set off to lessons, weighed down with
> books, parchment and quills as usual, but also with the lurking worry
> of the egg heavy in his stomach, as though he was carrying that around
> with him too.

Comment: It's unlikely that there are rules against champions helping each other, because nobody expects it. It's also not mentioned that Harry knows about such a rule. Your second quote doesn't support your point, it contradicts. Harry doubts this advice because it is vague "Harry, had told Cedric exactly what was coming in the first task – and Cedric’s idea of a fair exchange had been to tell Harry to take a bath." Or do you imply that Cedric wants his advice ignored?

Comment: @RalfFriedl - Most sports have codified rules about what players are and aren't allowed to do with each other, including what counts as collusion. He is giving him as much as he needs in order to find out for himself, with the added bonus that he is more likely to believe the answer if he works it out for himself.